# Mysql Update query to Update function

Tags: php, mysql

```
class loginattempts{
    public $max_attempts = 5;

    public function loginAttempts(){
    global $ALIST;
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $user_locked = "locked";


if($user_max_attempts >= $this->max_attempts){
            // update ip statue to locked //
            $attemtps_pdo = "UPDATE `attempts` SET `USER_STATUS`= ? WHERE IP = ?";
            $results = $ALIST->update($attempts_pdo,$user_locked,$user_ip);
            echo " locked";
        }else{
            // update ip attemtps ++ 1 //
            //add sql injection // 
            $attemtps_pdo = "UPDATE `attempts` SET `MAX_ATTEMPTS`= ? +1 WHERE IP = ?";
            $results = $ALIST->update($attempts_pdo,"MAX_ATTEMPTS",$user_ip);
            echo " is not locked";
        }
}
```

db.php

```
class data{

public function update($sql,$values1,$values2){
    $results = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    $results->bindValue(1,$values1);
    $results->bindValue(2,$values2);
    $results->execute();
}

$ALIST = new Data;

}
```

the connection to database had no problem , but once i bypass my UPDATE query to function update , my database wont update anymore , what i did wrong here?

Comment: what's error you are getting?

Comment: Would the second update work ever? Since you're binding a column name and it would be sent as a string, not part of the query

Comment: kamlesh.bar: no error but it wont update also.

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen:both update didt work , sorry what you mean ?

Comment: if there is no error that means re-check your update query. echo and paste query into phpmyadmin. you can always do try catch " try {
       $results->execute();
      // maybe do some logging here?
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      // maybe do some logging here?
      throw $e;
    }

Comment: i found the error  "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Answer (score 0):

check the spelling for your class, you used class **data** but this = $ALIST = new **Data**;

change the spellings and try again they must match.

And try specifing the update method in the data class in your loginattempts class to avoid any globals

Comment: i checked everything , i disable the global too (it work) but once i use global and get the data to update function it have error.

Comment: $attemtps_pdo = "UPDATE `attempts` SET `MAX_ATTEMPTS`= ? +1 WHERE IP = ?";

Comment: WHERE `IP` = ?' once i added this it wont work anymore.

Comment: Is IP a column name? if yes then check the data type of it in mysql. If it is set to int change it to varchar cos $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] will output it as string